# Injecting Angular2 Service into components base class

Tags: angular, service, code-injection

I want to create a base class for components to be able to do something common during the life-cycle of the components. I also need the base class to access some service. How do I inject it? Of course I can use a singleton instead of a service, but that would not be very angularish even not typescriptish, I suppose, since singletons are an anti-pattern there.
Greets,
Daniel

**EDIT:**

This is what is currently working, but I rather expected to make the ConnectionService @Injectable() and inject it into the RemoteController's constructor like Angular2 docs say, preferably without the necessity to add it to the child components providers list.

The Child Component:

```
@Component(...)
export class SomeComponent extends RemoteController {
    sendRequest() {
        this.request('something');
    }
}
```

The Base Class:

```
export class RemoteController implements OnInit {
    public connection: SocketIOClient.Socket;
    constructor() {
        this.connection = RemoteService.connect('ws://localhost:8500');
    }
    request(name: string) {
        this.connection.emit('request', name);
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        ...
    }
}
```

The Singleton Solution:

```
class ConnectionService {
    private sockets: { [key: string]: SocketIOClient.Socket };
    constructor() {
        debugger;
        this.sockets = {};
    } 
    connect(url: string) {
        return (url in this.sockets) ? this.sockets[url] : io.connect(url);
    }
}
let RemoteService = new ConnectionService();

export { RemoteService };
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular2 only supports constructor injection. If you have a super class and a sub class and you want to inject to the super class you have to add the constructor parameter to the sub class and forward it to the sub class

```
export class RemoteController implements OnInit {

    constructor(public connection: SocketIOClient.Socket) {
        this.connection = RemoteService.connect('ws://localhost:8500');
    }
```

```
@Component(...)
export class SomeComponent extends RemoteController {
    constructor(connection: SocketIOClient.Socket) {
      super(connection
```

Comment: This was definitely not what I wanted to hear. I also read a little bit about programmatic injection via the ReflectiveInjector, but I didn't get it to work alright. I'll investigate a little more before I accept this unsatisfying answer (thanks anyway Günter)

Comment: You still need to inject the application injector if you use `ReflectveInjector`. I posted some answers with example code. I wouldn't even try to work around, I don't think this will work out well.

Comment: it's important to *not* add "public", "private", or "protected" on the base class' constructor parms, otherwise you'll get a conflict.  The example correctly does not include them, but I was including them anyway, until I figured it out.